# How to retrieve the next value in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Hi I have an app that display the name and gender of the students. In my query, I limit the display to 20. How will I apply the display of 21-40 by clicking the next button. Also it will go back if i click previous.

> MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<Students> GetAll;
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ListView lv;
    Context context = this;
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
    Button btnprevious,btnnext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        //Add below lines to your original code
        try{
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Till here
        GetAll = dbhelper.getAll();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
    }



    public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ViewAdapter() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return GetAll.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
            }

            final TextView names = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doctorlist_name);
            final TextView gender = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doctorlist_gender);

            names.setText(GetAll.get(position).getname());
            gender.setText(GetAll.get(position).getgender());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

> DatabaseHelper class

```
public List<Students> getAll() {

        final int maxCount = 20;

        List<Students> sList = new ArrayList<Students>();
        {
            String selectQuery =
                    "SELECT id,full_name,gender FROM students LIMIT " +maxCount+" ";
            Log.e("students query: ", selectQuery);
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Students si = new Students();
                    si.setid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    si.setname(cursor.getString(1));
                    si.setgender(cursor.getString(2));

                    sList.add(si);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
        }
        return sList;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On next Button click increase index with 20 and on previous button click decrease the index to 20, You can achieve with below query.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT id,full_name,gender FROM students LIMIT 20, "+index;
```

Edit:

```
public List<Students> getStudent(int index) {
        final int maxCount = 20;
        List<Students> sList = new ArrayList<Students>();{
            String selectQuery = "SELECT id,full_name,gender FROM students LIMIT "+maxCount+", "+index;;
            Log.e("students query: ", selectQuery);
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Students si = new Students();
                    si.setid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    si.setname(cursor.getString(1));
                    si.setgender(cursor.getString(2));

                    sList.add(si);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
        }
        return sList;
}



private int currentPageIndex=0; 
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
     switch(view.getId()){
          case R.id.prevBtn;
                currentPageIndex -=20;
                GetStudent.clear();
                GetStudent.addAll(dbhelper.getStudent(int index));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
          case R.id.nextBtn;
                currentPageIndex +=20;
                GetStudent.clear();
                GetStudent.addAll(dbhelper.getStudent(int index));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: where i will insert that in my dbhelper class or in my main activity?sorry newbie to android

Comment: @GemUbaldo checkout the updated code. Use getStudent() method to retrieve students. Pass index from which you need to get Student. And as I earlier said,  On next Button click increase index with 20 and on previous button click decrease the index to 20.

Comment: i got error in my main activity in this line GetStudent = dbhelper.getStudent(int index);

Comment: dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        //Add below lines to your original code
        try{
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Till here
        GetStudent = dbhelper.getStudent(int index);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
    }

Comment: i replace GetAll = dbhelper.getAll(); with GetStudent = dbhelper.getStudent(int index);

Comment: What is GetAll and GetStudent? is it List?

Comment: yes in my code, GetAll is in the list. i want to display the first 20 then when i press next, 21-40 will replace the first 20 in listview

Comment: sorry if youre confuse i only googled the codes that i used

Comment: just replace GetAll = dbhelper.getStudent(), it should also work.

Comment: when i insert the int index in this line GetStudent = dbhelper.getStudent(int index); in my main activity

Comment: in the (int index); , the i and ) has red underline and it says ')' expected and ';' expected

Comment: Instead of  GetStudent = dbhelper.getStudent(int index);  you need to try GetStudent = dbhelper.getStudent(index);  remove int.

Comment: i try that also and i got error which was -> cannot resolve symbol 'index'

Comment: Have you declare any variable which will increase or decrease its value on next and previous button click.

Comment: You need to pass that variable instead of index. Or if you haven't  create one then please create one.

Comment: not yet sorry dont have an idea and also in my onclick listener

Comment: @GemUbaldo checkout the updated code. Still you need to put validation so that currentPageIndex can not go below 0 and can not go above max db row count.

Comment: thank you sir my only problem is in the adapter since i used custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the whereCluse:
for example next page: (page = 2)
id> 20*(page - 1) and LIMIT 20*(page)